# Facebook login issue in flutter, There was a problem verifying this package name. Please check and try again

Tags: flutter, flutter-facebook-login

I'm presently working on the Facebook login in flutter. In the developer console (https://developers.facebook.com/), I created the app and tried to add the bundle id in step 3 but it returns an error as **There was an issue confirming this package name. Please check and try again**.Please assist me in resolving this. Thank you ahead of time.

[ref image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1wDE.jpg)

Comment: packagename needs to be unique

Comment: Yes, I only tested the unique id. However, it does not function. In addition, I am unable to create or add a new app under the Facebook login quick start.

Comment: then issue might be with your facebook developer account

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234038/16607002

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred while attempting to add the package name to the meta for the Facebook dashboard. The meta team is currently working on resolving it.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/261648152949557